# Are the following BCP47 codes equally valid: art-x-isv-Latn or art-Latn-x-isv?

Tags: lang

The question arises from my doubt whether everything that follows `x-` in BCP47 code is a private extension as well. Will `Latn` be considered as a private extension too in `art-x-isv-Latn`? On the other hand, the latter looks more reasonable than `art-Latn-x-isv`, because if you read it:

- `art-x-isv-Latn`: a private extension of the artificial languages group under name "isv" (Interslavic), in Latin script
- `art-Latn-x-isv`: **the artificial language in Latin script** with the extension "isv" (Interslavic)

Could you help me with figuring out if my interpretation of `art-x-isv-Latn` and `art-Latn-x-isv` is correct in terms of BCP47?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m the editor of RFC 4645 and 5645 and the main clerical contributor to the BCP 47 Language Subtag Registry.

It is true that in BCP 47, everything following the **x** singleton is considered a private extension. Therefore, the correct way to write your tag is **art-Latn-x-isv**.

Variant subtags and especially private extensions can mean almost anything, so there is no one “right” place to put them within a tag that will always make the most sense from a grouping standpoint. Interpreting your tag as “the artificial language in Latin script with the extension ‘isv’ (Interslavic)” is not wrong. The extension refers to the entire preceding tag (“art-Latn”), not just the immediately preceding subtag (“Latn”).

Comment: I just wanted to express enormous gratitude for taking this issue in the loop so fast.

Hopefully, in the future, Interslavic becomes compliant to the requirements imposed by the registration authority and no longer will need -x-* extensions.
Nevertheless, having an expert answer about the correct temporary tag is priceless and will help in unifying our cross-developer efforts in the Interslavic domain.